# My css changes are not getting reflected when i run my website

Tags: python, django, static

In my directory i have de following:

```
-Proyecto
 -proyecto
 -static
   -css
     styles.css
   -images
 -tienda
```

in my settings.py file i already added my STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

And in my template called "tienda.html" i have the following:

```
{%load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

<h3>TIENDA</h3>
```

when i run my website with my localhost, no css changes are reflected.
I already tried deleting de cache from the explorers but still i can´t see any changes.

Comment: What about your .css file? Can you share it by editing your question?

Comment: may be space affected: put {% load static %} instead of {%load static%}.

Comment: I assume you are using the development `runserver` command. Try stopping and starting your development server.